# FCM notification alert isn't appearing in a popup when app is closed or background/foreground

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a chat app and I want FCM messages to appear in the background and foreground.  However, I can see the console log of the new message but it won't pop up even though I have alerts enabled.

It's appearing in the console.
[image]

Here's the messaging service:

```js
  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => {
      console.log('new msg', payload);
      alert(JSON.stringify(payload))
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    })
  }
```

app component:

```js
  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.storage.create();
    this.messagingService.receiveMessage();
    this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;
  }
```

angular.json

```js
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
            ],
```

I'm sending the request from Postman with the serverId and device token.  I followed the tutorial but in the tutorial the popup appears when sending the message from Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fetch push notifications when app is in background,

In your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file add the following code:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', 
  payload);
});
```

Now, in your `messaging service` file bind the function

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
(_messaging) => {
    _messaging.onBackgroundMessage = _messaging.onBackgroundMessage.bind(_messaging);        
});
```

More details can be found over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#web-version-9_3)